# How do I differentiate between two dropbox users in an app in Dropbox api V2 in objective-C

Tags: ios, sdk, objective-c-blocks, dropbox-api

In my app, there can be multiple users, and each user can link to their own dropbox account. Previously, I used

```
setSharedSession:
```

But now that there is no DBSession object, how can I let user register different dropbox. Everytime, one user is linking his dropbox, the previous one is getting replaced.

I am having real trouble with the new dropbox SDK (V2). How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Dropbox API v2 Objective-C SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c) documentation has information on supporting multiple different accounts via the SDK here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c#multiple-dropbox-user-case

For example, you can use `authorizedClients` instead of `authorizedClient` to access all of the saved clients.